# React build for subdirectory gives 404

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have added the link to sub directory in home page of package.json and added the sub directory in basename of router tag but it gives 404 page when click on any link ex. the application load the login(landing page `domain.com/subdirectory`) but after login it goes to (`domain.com/subdirectory/dashboard`) and it gives 404. I am not able understand what is wrong here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your code here

Comment: added the image for code

Comment: You should post code parts not images of your code it will much easier to follow the code.